# A question regarding 3D plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

**Updated**

I have an equation:

$x (z \ln z) = y$.

For different values of $x$ and $y$ we can solve this equation for z, for example, for $x = 3$ and $y =1$, we have:

```
FindRoot[3 z Log[z] == 1, {z, 0.1, 5}]
```

I like to have a 3D plot, where $x$ varies, for example, from $1$ to $3$, and $y$ from $2$ to $4$, and the third dimension to be the solutions of the equation, that is, $z$. How can I implement this in Mathematica?

**Edit:**

I need the command for solving the equation to be FindRoot.

Comment: Why do you need the command to be `FindRoot`? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: For comparison, [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) enables plotting without an explicit solution.

`ContourPlot3D[x z Log[z] == y,
 {x, 1, 3}, {y, 2, 4}, {z, 1.5, 3.5},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]`

Comment: @N.J.Evans The real equation that I wanted to solve it's only solvable with FindRoot.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve your equation for z

```
sol = Solve[x z Log[z] == y, z][[1]]
(*{z -> y/(x ProductLog[y/x])}*)
```

and plot z

```
Plot3D[z /. sol, {x, 1, 3}, {y, 2, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

numerical approach:

```
solu[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] :=z /. FindRoot[x z Log[z] == y, {z, 1}]
Plot3D[solu[x,y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 2, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I need to use FindRoot command. Can I just replace Solve with FindRoot?

Comment: The advantage of the symbolic solution would be lost. I'll modify my answer.